# What does the % operator do in Ruby in N % 2?

Tags: ruby, syntax

`if counter % 2 == 1`  I am trying to decode this line - it's a Rails project and I am trying to figure out what the `%` does in this if statement.

Comment: Smells like something to check for odd values of the counter.

Comment: A little puzzle for you: in C#, the test you give does *not* reliably check whether counter is odd. Does anyone see why? (Hint: in Ruby, what's the difference between the remainder and modulo methods on numerics?)

Comment: Also use for string substitutions - http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000770

Comment: What's wrong with `if counter.odd?` is the more interesting question here ...

Comment: @Eric, does C# do something silly like return -1 for negative odd values of counter?

Comment: http://codegoeshere.blogspot.com/2008/09/c-mod-operator-and-negative-numbers.html

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`%` is the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator) operator. The result of `counter % 2` is the remainder of `counter / 2`.

`n % 2` is often a good way of determining if a number `n` is even or odd. If `n % 2 == 0`, the number is even (because no remainder means that the number is evenly divisible by 2); if `n % 2 == 1`, the number is odd.

Comment: You *certain* about that last claim there? That's true in Ruby but not in other languages!

Comment: @Eric what's not true? I didn't say it's the only or best way of determining if a number is even or odd...

Comment: What I meant was that the test n%2==1 *does not actually determine if a number is odd* in many languages. In C# for instance it determines if a number is *both positive and odd*, which is different.

Comment: @Eric well I can't speak about languages I haven't used, and this question is specifically about Ruby...

Comment: Why would % in C# differentiate between positive and negative in mod 2? Since -a == a (mod 2) (this is trivial - take -a == -a (mod 2), and add 0 == 2a (mod 2)), I see no reason for the difference. Obviously, we don't have this restriction in other moduli. (1 == -2 (mod 3)).

Comment: thanks everyone.  I never got a notice this was answered I appreciate everyone's help

Answer (score 41):

In answer to the question "What does the % symbol do or mean in Ruby?" It is:

1. The modulo binary operator (as has been mentioned)

   ```
   17 % 10 #=> 7
   ```
2. The alternative string delimiter token

   ```
   %Q{hello world} #=> "hello world"
   %Q(hello world) #=> "hello world"
   %Q[hello world] #=> "hello world"
   %Q!hello world! #=> "hello world"
   # i.e. choose your own bracket pair
   %q(hello world) #=> 'hello world'
   %x(pwd)         #=> `pwd`
   %r(.*)          #=> /.*/
   ```
3. The string format operator (shorthand for Kernel::sprintf)

   ```
   "%05d" % 123 #=> "00123"
   ```

Comment: +1 for being the only one to mention the string format operator. That was the particular answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That's the modulo operator.  It gives the remainder when counter is divided by 2.

```
For example:
3 % 2 == 1  
2 % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how it works, the modulo operator is probably not the best code for the purpose (even though we are not given much context). As Jörg mentioned in a comment, the expression `if counter.odd?` is probably the intent, and is more readable.

If this is view code and used to determine (for example) alternating row colors, then you may be able to do without the counter altogether by using the built-in Rails helper `cycle()`. For example, you can use `cycle('odd','even')` as a class name for a table row, eliminating the counter and surrounding if/then logic.

Another thought: if this is within an `each` block, you may be able to use each_with_index and eliminate the extraneous counter variable.

My refactoring $0.02.

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that, Ruby's definition of the modulo (`%`) operator differs from that of C and Java. In Ruby, `-7%3` is `2`. In C and Java, the result is `-1` instead. In Ruby, the sign of the result (for `%` operator) is always the same as the sign of the second operand.

Answer (score 0):

Its the modulo operator.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0):

It is the modulo operator, which is a fancy way of saying it's the remainder operator.

So if you divided a number by two, and the integer remainder of that number is one, then you know the number was odd.  Your example checks for odd numbers.

Often this is done to highlight odd number rows with a different background color, making it easier to read large lists of data.

Answer (score 0):

To give a few ways to say it:

- Modulo operator
- Remainder operator
- Modular residue

Strictly speaking, if `a % b = c`, `c` is the unique constant such that

`a == c (mod b)` and `0 <= c < b`

Where `x == y (mod m)` iff `x - y = km` for some constant `k`.

This is equivalent to the remainder. By some well known theorem, we have that `a = bk + c` for some constant `k`, where `c` is the remainder, which gives us `a - c = bk`, which obviously implies `a == c (mod b)`.

(Is there a way to use LaTeX on Stackoverflow?)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic question. `%` is the modulo opereator `if counter % 2 == 1` results to `true` for every odd number and to `false` for every even number.

If you're learning ruby you should learn how to use `irb`, there you can try things out and perhaps answer the question yourself.

try to enter

```
100.times{|i| puts "#{i} % 2 == 1 #=> #{i % 2 == 1}"}
```

into your `irb` irb console and see the output, than it should be clear what `%` does.

And you really should take a look at the rails api documentation ([1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/index.html), [1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/index.html), [1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core/)), there you would have found the answer two your question [% (Fixnum)](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001059) with a further link to a detailed description  of [divmod (Numeric)](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Numeric.html#M000179):

> Returns an array containing the quotient and modulus obtained by dividing num by aNumeric. > If q, r = x.divmod(y), then
>
> ```
> q = floor(float(x)/float(y))
> x = q*y + r
> ```
>
> The quotient is rounded toward -infinity, as shown in the following table:
>
> ```
>  a    |  b  |  a.divmod(b)  |   a/b   | a.modulo(b) | a.remainder(b)
> ------+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+---------------
>  13   |  4  |   3,    1     |   3     |    1        |     1
> ------+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+---------------
>  13   | -4  |  -4,   -3     |  -3     |   -3        |     1
> ------+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+---------------
> -13   |  4  |  -4,    3     |  -4     |    3        |    -1
> ------+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+---------------
> -13   | -4  |   3,   -1     |   3     |   -1        |    -1
> ------+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+---------------
>  11.5 |  4  |   2,    3.5   |   2.875 |    3.5      |     3.5
> ------+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+---------------
>  11.5 | -4  |  -3,   -0.5   |  -2.875 |   -0.5      |     3.5
> ------+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+---------------
> -11.5 |  4  |  -3,    0.5   |  -2.875 |    0.5      |    -3.5
> ------+-----+---------------+---------+-------------+---------------
> -11.5 | -4  |   2    -3.5   |   2.875 |   -3.5      |    -3.5
> ```
>
> Examples
>
> ```
>  11.divmod(3)         #=> [3, 2]
>  11.divmod(-3)        #=> [-4, -1]
>  11.divmod(3.5)       #=> [3, 0.5]
>  (-11).divmod(3.5)    #=> [-4, 3.0]
>  (11.5).divmod(3.5)   #=> [3, 1.0]
> ```