# Incrementing wday in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am dealing with week days (wday) in rails. i.e. the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Not dates, just days of the week.

I need to translate Friday,Saturday,Sunday [4,5,6] into Saturday,Sunday,Monday [5,6,0]. If I just add 1 then I end up with [5,6,7] which is no good as day 7 does not exist. I need to wrap around the week end.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Try modulo, e.g. `wday % 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this weird little trick, the [modulo operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517238/125816):

```
def next_day(cur_day)
  max_day_number = 7
  (cur_day + 1) % max_day_number
end

next_day(4) # => 5
next_day(5) # => 6
next_day(6) # => 0
```

It ensures that if value were to exceed the limit (`max_day_number`), it would instead just wrap around to 0 and start over.

Comment: I need to use max_day_number = 7 for my example but that's perfect. I have not heard of modulo before - thanks - you have saved me a ton of time,

Comment: @user3565039 Why do you need max_day_number to be seven?

Comment: Because I want next_day(6) # => 0 not next_day(6) # => 1

Comment: @user3565039: ah! I messed up my snippet when editing. Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: The limit (`max_day_number`) is the number of days in a week, i.e. 7. It won't change :-)

Comment: @Stefan: classic case of "off by 1" error on my side :)